# Align edge path for childrens in forest

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-trees, forest

I am trying to align the edge path of my taxonomy using forest. I've looked at a lot of examples and documentation, without finding it. My knowledge in `tikz` is still very limited.

### MWE

Here is a MWE. The important part is that the children at level 1 have different width, which causes the path to have this disgraceful aspect.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree={
        grow=east,
        parent anchor=east,
        child anchor=west,
        align=center,
        anchor=base west,
        l sep+=10pt,
        tier/.pgfmath=level(),
        for root={
            rectangle,
            draw,
            parent anchor=east,
            },
        }
    [Taxonomy of Blah
        [Blah
            [Blah blah blah]
            [Blah]
            [Blah]
        ]
        [Blah blah blah
            [Blah]
            [Blah]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

### Output

Here is what I have so far, and what I try to achieve in red.

[image: Current output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a different `edge path'` in the definition of `forked edge'` (or a manual application of `edge path'`). We want to start at the child node, go a bit (`fork sep`) to the left, and then vertically+horizontally to the parent node.

I have also taken the liberty of cleaning up the code a bit. First, `for root` inside a `for tree` makes no sense and is in fact dangerous, as the given keys are executed many times; actually, `for root` is redundant, as all keys given in the tree preamble automatically apply to the root node. Second, it is not necessary to set `parent anchor` and `child anchor`.  Third, `align=center` is not needed when each node contains a single line; to achieve the unintended effect of making the nodes higher, use `inner ysep` (or `s sep`, for a similar effect). Finally, `.option` is faster than `.pgfmath`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\forestset{
  forked edge'/.style={
    edge={rotate/.option=!parent.grow},
    edge path'={
      (.child anchor)
      -- ++(-\forestoption{fork sep},0)
      |- (!u.parent anchor)
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    grow=east,
    inner ysep=1.2ex, 
    anchor=base west,
    l sep+=2em,
    fork sep=1.5em,
    tier/.option=level,
  },
  rectangle,
  draw,
  parent anchor=east,
  [Taxonomy of Blah
    [Blah
      [Blah blah blah]
      [Blah]
      [Blah]
    ]
    [Blah blah blah
      [Blah]
      [Blah]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted. I'm still unsure about this line though: `edge={rotate/.option=!parent.grow}`. Would you mind explaining what it does? I've seen it in the documentation, but I haven't seen details.

Comment: That code rotates the edge according to the parent's `grow`th direction. It is there to allow for forked edges in growth directions other than `east` (which is `grow=0`). Grow a tree in another direction and remove that key to see how things go wrong then.